# Map showing grid in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mkmapview

How would you display a Map on xamari.ios showing the users location but showing a grid instead of an actual map. This must include annotations of others users but it must only show their
 pins on a grid.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You do not even need a map, just draw your own grid, with the users location in the center and show the other users relative to that user ((current.lat - otheruser.lat) * someScaleConstant) , ((current.long - otheruser.long) * someScaleConstant) ....

Comment: Thank You for the help, I'll give this a try. Do you by any chance have any links or references for tutorials on how to achieve this?